# Multi-tempo/meter js DAW

Tags: javascript

Has anyone implemented a javascript audio DAW with multiple tempo and meter change capabilities like most of the desktop daws (pro tools, sonar, and the like)? As far as I can tell, [claw](https://github.com/mkascel/clawlab), [openDAW](https://github.com/pverrecchia/OpenDAW), and [web audio editor](https://github.com/janmyler/web-audio-editor) don't do this. Drawing a grid meter, converting between samples and MBT time, and rendering waveforms is easy when the tempo and meter do not change during the project, but when they do it gets quite a bit more complicated. I'm looking for any information on how to accomplish something like this. I'm aware that the source for Audacity is available, but I'd love to not have to dig through an enormous pile of code in a language I'm not an expert in to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

web-based DAW solutions exists.web-based DAW's are seen as SaaS(Software as a Service) applications.
They are lightweight and contain basic fundamental DAW features.
For designing rich client applications(RCA) you should take a look at GWT and Vaadin.

I recommend GWT because it is mature and has reusable components and its also AJAX driven.
Also here at [musicradar](http://www.musicradar.com/news/tech/9-ways-to-make-music-in-your-web-browser-490608/6) site they have listed nine different browser based audio workstations.you can also refer to [popcorn maker](https://popcorn.webmaker.org/) which is entirely javascript code.You can get some inspiration from there to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the last step, which will make it easier.

All measures are relative to fractions of minutes, based on the time-signature and tempo.

The math gets a little more complex, now that you can't just plot 4/4 or 6/8 across the board and be done with it, but what you're looking at is running an actual time-line (whether drawn onscreen or not), and then figuring out where each measure starts and ends, based on either the running sum of a track's current length (in minutes/seconds), or based on the left-most take's x-coordinate (starting point) + duration...

or based on the running total of each measure's length in seconds, up to the current beat you care about.

```
var measure = { beats : 4, denomination : 4, tempo : 80 };
```

Given those three data-points, you should be able to say:

```
var measure_length = SECONDS_PER_MINUTE / measure.tempo * measure.beats;
```

Of course, that's currently in seconds.  To get it in *ms*, you'd just use MS_PER_MINUTE, or whichever other ratio of minutes you'd want to measure by.

```
current_position + measure_length === start_of_next_measure;
```

You've now separated out each dimension required to allow you to calculate each measure on the fly.

Positioning each measure on the track, to match up with where it belongs on the timeline is as simple as keeping a running tally of where X is (the left edge of the measure) in ms (really in screen-space and project-coordinates, but ms can work fine for now).

```
var current_position     =   0,
    current_tempo        = 120,
    current_beats        =   4,
    current_denomination =   4,
    measures = [ ];

measures.forEach(function (measure) {
    if (measure.tempo !== current_tempo) {
        /* draw tempo-change, set current_tempo */
        /* draw time-signature */
    }
    if (measure.beats        !== current_beats ||
        measure.denomination !== current_denomination) {
        /* set changes, draw time-signature */
    }
    draw_measure(measure, current_position);
    current_position = MS_PER_MINUTE / measure.beats * measure.tempo;
});
```

Drawing samples just requires figuring out where you're starting from, and then sticking to some resolution (MS/MS*4/Seconds).

The added benefit of separating out the calculation of the time is that you can change the resolution of your rendering on the fly, by changing which time-scale you're comparing against (ms/sec/min/etc), so long as you re-render the whole thing, after scaling.

The rabbit hole goes deeper (for instance, actual audio tracks don't really care about measures/beats, though quantization-processes do), so to write a non-destructive, non-linear DAW, you can just set start-time and duration properties on views into your audio-buffer (or views into view-buffers of your audio buffer).
Those views would be the non-destructive windows that you can resize and drag around your track.

Then there's just the logic of figuring out snaps -- what your screen-space is, versus project-space, and when you click on a track's clip, which measure, et cetera, you're in, to do audio-snapping on resize/move.

Of course, to do a 1:1 recreation of ProTools in JS in the browser would not fly (gigs of RAM for one browser tab won't do, media capture API is still insufficient for multi-tracking, disk-writes are much, much more difficult in browser than in C++, in your OS of choice, et cetera), but this should at least give you enough to run with.

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Wow, give me a little while to look this over and i'll see if have any questions. Appreciate your time!

Comment: It seems no matter what I do I cannot seem to get anywhere near the performance of most modern daws with this. If I calculate everything on the fly, zooming and scrolling are slow and jerky. If I use a pre-calculated lookup table for every tick in the project Things run smoothly, but there is a big slowdown every time I want to change tempo. I'm missing something for sure.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp You're not likely to come close to a modern DAW, without doing it all in Canvas, in WebGL, with a finely-honed math library, built for performance (and even then, only if you're not writing to drive, etc). That said, if you're doing it all in-browser, using DOM elements, then one of the first things you should consider doing is making sure all of the calculations (for size/position) of elements are done separately from DOM rendering, and that DOM-building happens off-DOM (and appended after), and that there are `requestAnimationFrame`s to keep things bouncy.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp The other thing that you might be missing, which DAWs and videogames are good at, but websites are *not*, is rendering a selected view, based on the occlusion of other parts.  To put it in terms of an FPS game, if you stare North, down a hall, the CPU will still do all of the math needed for everything behind you to the South, but will save GPU time by not drawing it (the most expensive part). Likewise, nothing will be drawn past the door at the end of the hall (save for what you can directly see out the window), as the door blocks the view...

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp to take that example back to the DAW... I'm not sure how you're rendering it -- in HTML, in Canvas, SVG...  ...bits of all three for different pieces of the workspace...  ...but, to look at just the ticks in the timeline, in HTML, it would mean that you'd figure out where the left edge of the screen was, where the right was, and instead of making 40,000 `<span>`s for ticks, you'd calculate them all in-memory, and only make enough to fill the next screen and a half. As you move, take from the left and add to the right (off DOM, and append when they're all built).